# VB.NET TextBox to follow mouse cursor

Tags: vb.net, textbox, mouse-cursor

Does anybody know how can I make a TextBox follow the mouse cursor on a simple form?

Comment: That sounds like it would be an incredibly obnoxious UI... What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MouseMove` event handler of your form

```
textBox.Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y); Invalidate();
```

`e` is `MouseEventArgs`

Answer (score 0):

I've done this code for you, check this answer :

```
   Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
        Label1.Text = e.X.ToString
        Label2.Text = e.Y.ToString
        Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(e.X  + 10, e.Y + 10)

    End Sub
```

Comment: That kinda works like i want is it possible to have the textbox at a slight distance as as that i can still click other things on the form?

Comment: @BartvanTuÿl: Yes, just add a few pixels to the `e.X` and `e.Y` properties. Those are the X and Y values of the current mouse pointer's location. If you add a 20 or 25 pixel offset to each, then the control's new position will be offset 20 or 25 pixels from the mouse pointer's current location.

Comment: All you really need is the last line; change it to this: `Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(e.X + 25, e.Y + 25)`